# How to change device orientation without CSS and only with JavaScript or jQuery/jQueryMobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have the following HTML Structure:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageOne">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Titlu Aplicatie</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h1>Titlu Continut</h1>
            <h2>Subtitlu Continut</h2>
            <p>Text Continut aplicatie</p>
            <div class="change">La click pe acest element schimbam orientarea dispozitivului !</div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Aplicatie</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

and what I want to do is to change the device orientation with JavaScript, jQuery or jQueryMobile only and WITHOUT the use of CSS when the user makes a click on the `<div>` HTML Element on the page.

I know how to do it with CSS like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div.change").on("click", function () {
                function reorient(e) {
                    var portrait = (window.orientation % 90 == 0);
                    $("body").css("-webkit-transform", !portrait ? "rotate(-90deg)" : "");
                }
                window.onorientationchange = reorient;
                window.setTimeout(reorient, 0);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But I want to do it with JavaScript, jQuery/jQuery Mobile only.

Is there by any chance a way of doing it without the use of native code ? Any hint/help is appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: What does "without css" and "without the use of native code" mean? - Why are you even trying to control the orientation? So many confusing things!

Comment: Basically when I click on that DIV element a popup will appear but I want it to appear in landscape mode along with the orientation of the page in the same landscape mode. So I need a way to change the orientation of the page when I click on a HTML element. I need a way to do it without the use of CSS because I want it to run faster without any need to process extra CSS code and I don't know objective-c or other mobile programming language. I'm using jQuery Mobile with Cordova Framework for developing.

Comment: @bookw0rm Try this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation if you are using cordova

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in the comments that you are using Cordova for developing mobile application.So my suggestion is to make use of the below Cordova plugin for screen orientation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

After installing the plugin,now you can change your device orientation when you click on your div with

```
$("div").on("click",function(){
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
});
```

There are additional usages available in plugin like

```
// allow user rotate 
screen.unlockOrientation();

// access current orientation 
console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation);
```